# Redis works on deployment , It doesn't work on production with docker and heroku

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, redis, docker-compose

I am trying to develop an express api.It works on local machine as expected. I am using docker but on production with docker and heroku redis is not working

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

docker.compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
  
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    

  app:
    container_name: password-manager-docker
    image: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
    links: 
      - mongo
      - redis
    environment: 
      MONGODB_URI: ${MONGODB_URI}
      REDIS_URL: ${REDIS_URL}   
      clientID: ${clientID}
      clientSecret : ${clientSecret}
      PORT: ${PORT}
      REDIS_HOST: ${REDIS_HOST}
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      JWT_EXPIRE: ${JWT_EXPIRE}
      REFRESH_TOKEN: ${REFRESH_TOKEN}
      JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY}
      JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE: ${JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE}
      JWT_COOKIE: ${JWT_COOKIE}
      SMTP_HOST: ${SMTP_HOST}
      SMTP_PORT: ${SMTP_PORT}
      SMTP_USER: ${SMTP_USER}
      SMTP_PASS: ${SMTP_PASS}
```

redis file

```
const asyncRedis = require('async-redis');
//process.env.REDIS_HOST's value is redis
const redisClient = asyncRedis.createClient({port:6379,host:process.env.REDIS_HOST || "127.0.0.1"});
redisClient.on("connect",() => {
  console.log(`Redis: ${host}:${port}`);
})
redisClient.on('error', function(err) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`[Redis] Error ${err}`);
});
```

The error on heroku is "[Redis] Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379". It worked without docker on heroku but not It is not working. Thanks for your help

Comment: Check whether the redis sever is running or not

Comment: Api works what I was expected on local and redis server is running

Comment: Are you setting the `$REDIS_HOST` environment variable?  In the context of this Compose setup, does it work to set it to the fixed container name in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: yes I set up it as redis

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.I changed redis addon in heroku from heroku redis to redis to go and changed this line

```
const redisClient = asyncRedis.createClient({port:6379,host:process.env.REDIS_HOST || "127.0.0.1"});
```

to

```
const redisClient = asyncRedis.createClient(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install redis

   `sudo apt-get install redis-server`
2. Run command to check if everything is fine

   `sudo service redis-server status`

And if you get the message `redis-server is running` then it'll resove

Comment: I am using windows machine and also my problem is on production not local

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `REDIS_HOST` isn't set - you have the answer already in your question, error is: `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`
The hostaddress is comming from your if statement: `{port:6379,host:process.env.REDIS_HOST || "127.0.0.1"}`
If process.env.REDIS_HOST is not set, then use 127.0.0.1 as hostaddress. You have to parse a config file or set it via `-e KEY=VAL` when you run docker-compose or just edit the line `REDIS_HOST: ${REDIS_HOST}` and replace `${REDIS_HOST}` with the service name (redis) from the docker-compose.yml file  or..., there are a lot of possibilities. If you want to know the real ip of the redis container, just check with `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <CONTAINER_ID/NAME>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already set  the REDIS_HOST=redis in .env

Comment: I set in heroku also . [Redis] Error Error: Redis connection to redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis

Comment: Can you help if you are available

Comment: ah heroku is your prod environment?! Not sure how that works, docker-compose and .env is for local development and all you can do with heroku is pushing your container images to them (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose). The whole information with docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile and .env-file seems useless, you dont push redis and mongo container to heroku, you use their redis/mongo containers and documentation doesn't say much about starting containers (only took a short look).

Comment: So,what should exactly I do ? Any recommendation ?